# Using await on list joined with db object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a linq query as :

```
IGetAll.cs
public Iqueryable<ClassB> GetAll()
{
 _entityframeworkService.GetAllAsync();
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
List<Class1> listClass = data;//readily available

var result = (from list in listClass
              join _getAll.GetAll()
              select list);
var extractedResult = await result; //Error listClass cannot be awaited
```

Basically I have a list already (listClass) and want to join with db query object which can awaited (_getAll.GetAll()). How can I use await in this case?

if my listClass is also dbObject I could have used await easily

Comment: Neither of those things seem awaitable. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @CaiusJard: Edited GetAll() method to make it awaitable

Comment: You can't await a list. Not sure why you would want to either. You can only await methods that return a Task or Task<T>

Comment: @mason . Yes but the other method in Join condition  _getAll.GetAll() is a db operation which can be awaited . So in this scenario cant we use await in linq query is my question

Comment: Again: if you want to await a method, that method needs to return a Task or Task<T>. So....GetAll needs to return a `Task<Iqueryable<ClassB>>` instead of `Iqueryable<ClassB>`. You should also make sure it awaits the call to `_entityframeworkService.GetAllAsync()`.

Comment: I dont use query syntax a lot, but I suppose it would look like `join (await _getAll.GetAllAsync())` but it's a client side eval - if you're thinking to use those list IDs to e.g. perform something like an SQL `IN` then you'd write the query differently

Comment: Why are you wrapping Entity Framework? What is the point of IGetAll.cs?

Comment: @mason Its just a wrapper around Context class

Comment: Why? Why do you need a wrapper around it?